# Magento 2 - storeInfo

Tags: magento2, soap

i'm using soap C#

in magento 1 we could get the store info my passing in the store id

what is the method called in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/V1/store/storeViews` with filter by id

Answer (score 0):

finally found the service

it wasn't listed in the soap 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/soap/bk-soap.html

but listed in the rest api storeStoreRepositoryV1
http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html